# C# loading data from text file

Tags: c#

So I'm trying to load some data from a text file when the user types 'Load'. I have it sort of working, but there's a bug with it, it seems.

Let's say you buy an axe, which is 70 coins. You start with 100 coins, so you're left with 30 coins. You decide to save and exit the game. You come back and load your saved game, and you have 49 coins and 48 health points.

It also does the exact same thing when you save straight away with all the default values. I don't have any idea where it's get the value of 49 and 48 from.

```
const string f = "savedgame.txt";

        using (StreamReader r = new StreamReader(f))
        {

            string line;
            while ((line = r.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                player.gold = line[0];
                player.health = line[1];
                Console.WriteLine("Your game has been loaded.");
                menu.start(menu, shop, player, fishing, woodcut, mine, monster, quests, save, load);
            }
        }
```

This is my text file that I've just saved now.

```
100
20
1
0
0
5
```

I've tried examples off Google, but they did the same thing. So I did a bit of research and made one myself.... Did the same thing.

I don't know how much I can show you guys, but I can show more if needed.

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Since `line` is a single string, `line[0]` and `line[1]` actually refer to individual *characters* in the current line, not the first and second lines. For instance, if `line` is `100`, then that would be the ascii values of `1` and `0`, which are `49` and `48`, respectively.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are two problems with your current approach -

First, your logic is currently working on the characters of the first line -

The first time through your loop, line is `"100"`, so `line[0]` is `1`.  This is a `char` of `'1'`, not the value 1, so `player.gold = line[0]` translates into setting `player.gold` to the numerical equivelent of the character '1', which is 49.

Second, you're starting a loop and reading line by line, and then doing your work instead of reading all of the lines at once.

You can solve these issues by reading all of the lines at once, and working line by line.  Then you also need to convert the entire line to a number, not read one character:

```
const string f = "savedgame.txt";

var lines = File.ReadAllLines(f);
player.gold = Convert.ToInt32(lines[0]);
player.health = Convert.ToInt32(lines[1]);
```

Answer (score 0):

r is a string, not an array of lines.  you're trying to set gold to the first character of the first line, and health to the second character, etc.